# Women giving birth to missiles?

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story or novel in which women (possibly third world) are conscripted to giving birth to missiles (or perhaps some other kind of weapon). Ring any bells?

Comment: [Sounds like an Oatmeal comic come to life...](http://s3.amazonaws.com/theoatmeal-img/comics/oatmeal_day/crotch_rockets.png)

Comment: Did you actually read the story, or are you going on something you heard about? When did you read it, or hear about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be ["Piecework"](http://www.smashwords.com/books/view/243397) by David Brin.

> In this chilling, award-nominated tale, a master of modern science fiction lets us glimpse an all-too possible near future when science, economics and individual dignity clash across the most intimate battlefield of all -- pregnancy. Might poor women earn a living by renting out their wombs for industrial "piecework" production of high-end organic machinery?

Comment: It's been years since I read this story, so I can't recall whether there was anything specifically about weapons.

Comment: No weapons in this story, but that story is also what came to my mind when I read “women giving birth to …”. However another difference is that the women are not conscripted, it's a voluntary thing — basically a job.